# Dialog flow number to string

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using an inline editor for fulfillment. I have a tracking number field and if the API returns 1234. The agent says one thousand two hundred and thirty-four. I want it to say 1 2 3 4. ANy idea how to do this will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you space separate the string "1234" to "1 2 3 4"?

Comment: 1234 is  returned by the api, so I cannot manipulate it 
here is teh code agent.add(` the tracking number is ${trackstat} .`);

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your flow is calling the API?  Is it your Dialogflow Webhook?  How does that relate to the API that returns "1234"?  If you know that the API returns a tracking number, can you not translate that into space separated string before returning from the fulfillment?

Comment: Your code fragment looks like JavaScript.  If so, can you use let myString = trackstat.split("").join(" ");     This might create a space separated representation of your data.

Comment: that worked ..thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

When a fulfillment returns a text string, that string will be returned to the user translated into speech.  The text to speech engine will do its best to translate the data.  If we give it a string of "1234" it will translate that into "One thousand, two hundred and thirty four".  If what we want is the translation "one two three four" we need to give guidance to the translation.  If we space separate characters, they will be sounded out.  This means that if we return "1 2 3 4" we will obtain the desired result.

In JavaScript, we can space separate a string by using the split() and join() functions.  Split separates a string into pieces and join combines pieces to form a string.

The following snippet will transform a string by separating its characters and build a new one space separated.

```
let data = "1234";
data = data.split("").join(" ");
// data here is now "1 2 3 4"
```